# В phpstorm emmet не корректно работает с html тегами

Tags: html, phpstorm, emmet

В phpstorm emmet заменяет угловые скобки в тегах сущностями html.

Пример: `a{ENTER}`, получаем - `&lt;a href=""&gt;&lt;/a&gt;`

Плюс к этому все пишет в одну строку `ul>li*2{ENTER}`, получаем - `&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

Если кто столкнется - оказывается дело в галке "Escape" в настройках Emmet, там, где "Filters enabled by default"